# maven install how to install and deploy *ONLY* ejb-client

Tags: java, maven, ejb

I'm using the *maven-ejb-plugin* to generate ejb client for my client, in the standard way

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-ejb-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.3</version>
    <configuration>
        <ejbVersion>3.0</ejbVersion>
        <generateClient>true</generateClient>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

So the client use its dependecy

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>en.foo.ejb</groupId>
    <artifactId>artifact-ejb</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.0</version>
    <type>ejb-client</type>         
</dependency>
```

I'm having 2 issues so far:

1. Launching `mvn clean install` or `mvn clean deploy` install ALSO the whole ejb package jar, so in the end I'll have both

   - *artifact-ejb.jar*
   - *artifact-ejb-client.jar*

I'd expect to install only the second one, because the artifact-ejb.jar should not be installed on the repository

2. The ejb artifact includes a **parent pom**, so when the client try to resolve all the dependencies it says **the parent pom cannot be found on the repository**, however the parent it is not meant to be distributed because it is only a reference.

(see also https://howtodoinjava.com/maven/maven-parent-child-pom-example/)

How can I solve these issues ?

Comment: This is the default way to do this. I don't see any issue with installing the `artifact-ejb.jar` ? What is the real problem? Apart from that the dependencies are also in the `artifact-ejb-client` furthermore you need to give the classifier in your dependency usage...That seemed to be a problem..

Comment: > I don't see any issue with installing the artifact-ejb.jar ? What is the real problem?
Maybe because you are installing all the business logic classes into repository. It makes no sense at all

Answer (score 1):

Your `artifact-ejb-client.jar` contains only the interfaces. At runtime, you need to have the implementations as well. So if you want to build a proper ear or war, you need both `artifact-ejb-client.jar` and `artifact-ejb.jar`. The only exception that comes to my mind is RMI communication where you would be fine having only the client (on the calling side). So think about whether you really want to keep the `artifact-ejb.jar` out of your repository.

If you decide to do so, split your project into two separate projects, one containing the interfaces and one containing the implementations. The impl-project needs the client-project as dependency. Then you can freely build and deploy just one of the two.

For the parent poms: All parent poms of your artifacts need to be in the repository, otherwise the builds will break. If you depend on an artifact, you need to resolve its parent pom. It cannot be kept "secret".

Comment: About the parent pom, the problem is that "mvn clean install" install all the submodules, this is not a desired effect

Comment: What do you mean by "submodule"? Do you have a multi-module project? Usually multi-module projects are built and installed as a whole. If you do not want that, think about splitting it up.

Comment: In Nexus/Artifactory, an artifact is only useful (as a dependency for other projects), if its parent pom and dependencies are also present.

Comment: Yes, I have an ear project with submodules, it a common practice in maven

Comment: I am not criticising your for having a multi-module project. But if you have one, you usually built, install and deploy the whole thing. You _can_ build parts of it, (see e.g. the commands in the middle of http://files.zeroturnaround.com/pdf/Maven-cheat-sheet.pdf) but you need to make sure that everything is consistent (i.e. if you deploy an artifact, you also deploy its dependencies and its parent pom).